# Vertical Spacing Within A Div Tag

Tags: html, css, navigationbar, divider

I've been working on a website in which you can access the information for many different songs, including artist, album, length, etc. On the homepage, I have a navigation bar fixed to the left of the screen(25% in width). It has a home link, and a link to every letter(the songs are organized in sections based on their first letter). In a perfect world, I would want all these links to fit perfectly vertical in this div, however this is not the case. When I open the website on different screens, there is always different amounts of 'excess' below the 'Z'.

The navigation bar looks a little like this:

```
Home
A
B
C
D
...
Z
(This is where the unused space is)
```

Here is my code:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}
/* Navigation Menu Styling */

ul.main-menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
ul.main-menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 7.45px 0 7.45px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul.main-menu li a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
/* Text Styling */

h1,
h2,
p {
  font-family: Calibri
}
p a:link,
p a:visited {
  font-family: Times New Roman;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
p a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#a_songs">A</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#b_songs">B</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#c_songs">C</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#d_songs">D</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#e_songs">E</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#f_songs">F</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#g_songs">G</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#h_songs">H</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#i_songs">I</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#j_songs">J</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#k_songs">K</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#l_songs">L</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#m_songs">M</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#n_songs">N</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#o_songs">O</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#p_songs">P</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#q_songs">Q</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#r_songs">R</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#s_songs">S</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#t_songs">T</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#u_songs">U</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#v_songs">V</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#w_songs">W</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#x_songs">X</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#y_songs">Y</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#z_songs">Z</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div style="margin-left:25%;padding:1px 16px;height:1000px;">
  <h1 id="home">Welcome To Name That Artist</h2>
    <p> You can find information about a song from the wide selection we offer.</p>
    <h3>Use the navigation bar to jump to a letter or search for a specific song.</h3>
    <hr id="a_songs"/><p align="center">A</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="all_of_me_john_legend" href="songs/a/All_Of_Me_John_Legend.html">All Of Me - John Legend</a>
       <a href="songs/a/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/a/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="b_songs"/><p align="center">B</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="bad_blood_bastille" href="songs/b/Bad_Blood_Bastille.html">Bad Blood - Bastille</a>
       <a href="songs/b/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/b/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="c_songs"/><p align="center">C</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="cake_by_the_ocean_dnce" href="songs/c/Cake_By_The_Ocean_DNCE.html">Cake By The Ocean - DNCE</a>
       <a href="songs/c/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/c/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="d_songs"/><p align="center">D</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="dont_stop_believin_journey" href="songs/d/Dont_Stop_Believin_Journey.html">Don't Stop Believin' - Journey</a>
       <a href="songs/d/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/d/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="e_songs"/><p align="center">E</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="eye_of_the_tiger_survivor" href="songs/e/Eye_Of_The_Tiger_Survivor.html">Eye Of The Tiger - Survivor</a>
       <a href="songs/e/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/e/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div> 
    <hr id="f_songs"/><p align="center">F</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="feel_good_robin_thicke" href="songs/f/Feel_Good_Robin_Thicke.html">Feel Good - Robin Thicke</a>
       <a href="songs/f/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/f/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="g_songs"/><p align="center">G</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="geronimo_sheppard" href="songs/g/Geronimo_Sheppard.html">Geronimo - Sheppard</a>
       <a href="songs/g/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/g/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="h_songs"/><p align="center">H</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="here_alessia_cara" href="songs/h/Here_Alessia_Cara.html">Here - Alessia Cara</a>
       <a href="songs/h/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/h/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="i_songs"/><p align="center">I</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="i_write_sins_not_tragedies_panic_at_the_disco" href="songs/i/I_Write_Sins_Not_Tragedies_Panic_At_The_Disco.html">I Write Sins Not Tragedies - Panic! At The Disco</a>
       <a href="songs/i/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/i/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="j_songs"/><p align="center">J</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="just_give_me_a_reason_pink" href="songs/j/Just_Give_Me_A_Reason_Pink.html">Just Give Me A Reason - P!nk</a>
       <a href="songs/j/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/j/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="k_songs"/><p align="center">K</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="kill_of_the_night_gin_wigmore" href="songs/k/Kill_Of_The_Night_Gin_Wigmore.html">Kill Of The Night - Gin Wigmore</a>
       <a href="songs/k/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/k/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="l_songs"/><p align="center">L</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="latch_disclosure" href="songs/l/Latch_Disclosure.html">Latch - Disclosure</a>
       <a href="songs/l/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/l/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="m_songs"/><p align="center">M</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="me_and_my_broken_heart_rixton" href="songs/m/Me_And_My_Broken_Heart_Rixton.html">Me And My Broken Heart - Rixton</a>
       <a href="songs/m/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/m/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="n_songs"/><p align="center">N</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="the_nights_avicci" href="songs/n/The_Nights_Avicci.html">The Nights - Avicci</a>
       <a href="songs/n/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/n/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="o_songs"/><p align="center">O</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="on_my_mind_ellie_goulding" href="songs/o/On_My_Mind_Ellie_Goulding.html">On My Mind - Ellie Goulding</a>
       <a href="songs/o/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/o/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="p_songs"/><p align="center">P</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="paradise_coldplay" href="songs/p/Paradise_Coldplay.html">Paradise - Coldplay</a>
       <a href="songs/p/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/p/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="q_songs"/><p align="center">Q</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a href="songs/q/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/q/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/q/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="r_songs"/><p align="center">R</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="rather_be_clean_bandit" href="songs/r/Rather_Be_Clean_Bandit.html">Rather Be - Clean Bandit</a>
       <a href="songs/r/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/r/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="s_songs"/><p align="center">S</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="secrets_coldplay" href="songs/s/Secrets_Coldplay.html">Secrets - Coldplay</a>
       <a href="songs/s/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/s/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="t_songs"/><p align="center">T</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="this_is_how_we_do_katy_perry" href="songs/t/This_Is_How_We_Do_Katy_Perry.html">This Is How We Do - Katy Perry</a>
       <a href="songs/t/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/t/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="u_songs"/><p align="center">U</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="uma_thurman_fall_out_boy" href="songs/u/Uma_Thurman_Fall_Out_Boy.html">Uma Thurman - Fall Out Boy</a>
       <a href="songs/u/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/u/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="v_songs"/><p align="center">V</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="victorious_panic_at_the_disco" href="songs/v/Victorious_Panic_At_The_Disco.html">Victorious - Panic! At The Disco</a>
       <a href="songs/v/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/v/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="w_songs"/><p align="center">W</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="want_to_want_me_jason_derulo" href="songs/w/Want_To_Want_Me_Jason_Derulo.html">Want To Want Me - Jason Derulo</a>
       <a href="songs/w/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/w/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="x_songs"/><p align="center">X</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="xo_the_eden_project" href="songs/x/XO_The_Eden_Project.html">XO - The Eden Project</a>
       <a href="songs/x/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/x/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="y_songs"/><p align="center">Y</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="you_know_you_like_it_dj_snake" href="songs/y/You_Know_You_Like_It_DJ_Snake.html">You Know You Like It - DJ Snake</a>
       <a href="songs/y/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/y/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="z_songs"/><p align="center">Z</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a href="songs/z/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/z/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/z/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: so are you saying you want to make each of those links 1/26th of the viewport height?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm wanting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would use relative sizing on the height to do this.  Basically, set the height and font-size of the links to a percentage of the viewport with the `vh` unit of measure.

https://jsfiddle.net/6ksL4845/

```
ul.main-menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  height:3.3vh;
  font-size:3vh;
  padding:0.2vh 5%;
}
```

Also, an unsolicited suggestion to simplify your markup (also shown in fiddle:

you might change:

```
<hr id="a_songs"/><p align="center">A</p><hr/>
```

to:

```
<p id="a_songs" class="letter_heading"/>A</p>
```

and add this to your CSS:

```
 .letter_heading  {
   border-top:1px solid #bbb;
   border-bottom:1px solid #bbb;
   padding:15px 0px;
   text-align:center;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `display:flex`on ul  and `flex:1;` on li, so they spray evenly on the whole area avalaible (or shrink on themselves).

---

**edit** : added an extra level of flexbox to wrap all letters at screen
 snippet updated and  [DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/yOdqxa) to play with and fork

---

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}
/* Navigation Menu Styling */


ul.main-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
ul.main-menu li {
  flex: 1;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;  
}
ul.main-menu li a {
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  flex:1;
}

/* end flex model */

ul.main-menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
ul.main-menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul.main-menu li a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
/* Text Styling */

h1,
h2,
p {
  font-family: Calibri
}
p a:link,
p a:visited {
  font-family: Times New Roman;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
p a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#a_songs">A</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#b_songs">B</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#c_songs">C</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#d_songs">D</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#e_songs">E</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#f_songs">F</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#g_songs">G</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#h_songs">H</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#i_songs">I</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#j_songs">J</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#k_songs">K</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#l_songs">L</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#m_songs">M</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#n_songs">N</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#o_songs">O</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#p_songs">P</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#q_songs">Q</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#r_songs">R</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#s_songs">S</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#t_songs">T</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#u_songs">U</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#v_songs">V</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#w_songs">W</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#x_songs">X</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#y_songs">Y</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#z_songs">Z</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div style="margin-left:25%;padding:1px 16px;height:1000px;">
  <h1 id="home">Welcome To Name That Artist</h2>
    <p> You can find information about a song from the wide selection we offer.</p>
    <h3>Use the navigation bar to jump to a letter or search for a specific song.</h3>
    <hr id="a_songs"/><p align="center">A</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="all_of_me_john_legend" href="songs/a/All_Of_Me_John_Legend.html">All Of Me - John Legend</a>
       <a href="songs/a/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/a/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="b_songs"/><p align="center">B</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="bad_blood_bastille" href="songs/b/Bad_Blood_Bastille.html">Bad Blood - Bastille</a>
       <a href="songs/b/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/b/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="c_songs"/><p align="center">C</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="cake_by_the_ocean_dnce" href="songs/c/Cake_By_The_Ocean_DNCE.html">Cake By The Ocean - DNCE</a>
       <a href="songs/c/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/c/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="d_songs"/><p align="center">D</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="dont_stop_believin_journey" href="songs/d/Dont_Stop_Believin_Journey.html">Don't Stop Believin' - Journey</a>
       <a href="songs/d/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/d/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="e_songs"/><p align="center">E</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="eye_of_the_tiger_survivor" href="songs/e/Eye_Of_The_Tiger_Survivor.html">Eye Of The Tiger - Survivor</a>
       <a href="songs/e/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/e/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div> 
    <hr id="f_songs"/><p align="center">F</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="feel_good_robin_thicke" href="songs/f/Feel_Good_Robin_Thicke.html">Feel Good - Robin Thicke</a>
       <a href="songs/f/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/f/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="g_songs"/><p align="center">G</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="geronimo_sheppard" href="songs/g/Geronimo_Sheppard.html">Geronimo - Sheppard</a>
       <a href="songs/g/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/g/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="h_songs"/><p align="center">H</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="here_alessia_cara" href="songs/h/Here_Alessia_Cara.html">Here - Alessia Cara</a>
       <a href="songs/h/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/h/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="i_songs"/><p align="center">I</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="i_write_sins_not_tragedies_panic_at_the_disco" href="songs/i/I_Write_Sins_Not_Tragedies_Panic_At_The_Disco.html">I Write Sins Not Tragedies - Panic! At The Disco</a>
       <a href="songs/i/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/i/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="j_songs"/><p align="center">J</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="just_give_me_a_reason_pink" href="songs/j/Just_Give_Me_A_Reason_Pink.html">Just Give Me A Reason - P!nk</a>
       <a href="songs/j/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/j/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="k_songs"/><p align="center">K</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="kill_of_the_night_gin_wigmore" href="songs/k/Kill_Of_The_Night_Gin_Wigmore.html">Kill Of The Night - Gin Wigmore</a>
       <a href="songs/k/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/k/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="l_songs"/><p align="center">L</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="latch_disclosure" href="songs/l/Latch_Disclosure.html">Latch - Disclosure</a>
       <a href="songs/l/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/l/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="m_songs"/><p align="center">M</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="me_and_my_broken_heart_rixton" href="songs/m/Me_And_My_Broken_Heart_Rixton.html">Me And My Broken Heart - Rixton</a>
       <a href="songs/m/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/m/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="n_songs"/><p align="center">N</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="the_nights_avicci" href="songs/n/The_Nights_Avicci.html">The Nights - Avicci</a>
       <a href="songs/n/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/n/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="o_songs"/><p align="center">O</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="on_my_mind_ellie_goulding" href="songs/o/On_My_Mind_Ellie_Goulding.html">On My Mind - Ellie Goulding</a>
       <a href="songs/o/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/o/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="p_songs"/><p align="center">P</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="paradise_coldplay" href="songs/p/Paradise_Coldplay.html">Paradise - Coldplay</a>
       <a href="songs/p/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/p/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="q_songs"/><p align="center">Q</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a href="songs/q/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/q/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/q/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="r_songs"/><p align="center">R</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="rather_be_clean_bandit" href="songs/r/Rather_Be_Clean_Bandit.html">Rather Be - Clean Bandit</a>
       <a href="songs/r/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/r/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="s_songs"/><p align="center">S</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="secrets_coldplay" href="songs/s/Secrets_Coldplay.html">Secrets - Coldplay</a>
       <a href="songs/s/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/s/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="t_songs"/><p align="center">T</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="this_is_how_we_do_katy_perry" href="songs/t/This_Is_How_We_Do_Katy_Perry.html">This Is How We Do - Katy Perry</a>
       <a href="songs/t/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/t/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="u_songs"/><p align="center">U</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="uma_thurman_fall_out_boy" href="songs/u/Uma_Thurman_Fall_Out_Boy.html">Uma Thurman - Fall Out Boy</a>
       <a href="songs/u/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/u/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="v_songs"/><p align="center">V</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="victorious_panic_at_the_disco" href="songs/v/Victorious_Panic_At_The_Disco.html">Victorious - Panic! At The Disco</a>
       <a href="songs/v/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/v/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="w_songs"/><p align="center">W</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="want_to_want_me_jason_derulo" href="songs/w/Want_To_Want_Me_Jason_Derulo.html">Want To Want Me - Jason Derulo</a>
       <a href="songs/w/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/w/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="x_songs"/><p align="center">X</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="xo_the_eden_project" href="songs/x/XO_The_Eden_Project.html">XO - The Eden Project</a>
       <a href="songs/x/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/x/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="y_songs"/><p align="center">Y</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a id="you_know_you_like_it_dj_snake" href="songs/y/You_Know_You_Like_It_DJ_Snake.html">You Know You Like It - DJ Snake</a>
       <a href="songs/y/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/y/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
    <hr id="z_songs"/><p align="center">Z</p><hr/>
     <div>
      <p>
       <a href="songs/z/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/z/.html"> </a>
       <a href="songs/z/.html"> </a>
      </p>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: This works great on larger screens, but it will scroll if the window is smaller than the total height of the `<li>` elements.  I guess ''fit perfectly vertical' isn't as clear as it could be - I interpreted it differently in my answer, but this is a nice way to go, as well.

Comment: @ryantdecker well it is meant to scroll at first, i understood issue was the Z not going all the way down when heights taller than the menu itself :)

Comment: yeah, when I saw your answer I read the question again, I can see it that way too...curious which was actually the desired behavior :-)

Comment: Hey guys, I'm a little new to the site so I didn't make the question as specific as I should have. I would like there to be no extra space under the letter Z and no scroll bar.

Comment: @JusThatGuy , okay, so should be when the all alphabet cannot be stacked ? what behavior do you expect, i believe you want each letter readable and away from each others :)

Comment: @JusThatGuy , just edited the snippet with an extra level of flex ., you can also play with this codepen http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/yOdqxa